# FireMonkey TPathData flatten : M0,0

Tags: delphi, path, firemonkey, flatten

What is this extra M0,0

Just one is enough.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PathD : TPathData;
  po1 : TPolygon;
begin
  PathD := TPathData.Create;
  PathD.Data := 'M0,0 L0,100 L100,100 L100,0 L0,0 Z';//PathArray[0].Data.Data;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(PathD.Data);
  PathD.Flatten();
  Memo1.Lines.Add(PathD.Data);
  PathD.Flatten();
  Memo1.Lines.Add(PathD.Data);
  PathD.Flatten();
  Memo1.Lines.Add(PathD.Data);
end;
```

Extra M0,0 available here.
Only one M0,0 should be.
M0,0 = Move(0,0);

Out Memo1:

```
M0,0 L0,100 L100,100 L100,0 L0,0 Z 

M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 L0,100 L100,100 L100,0 L0,0 Z 

M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0
M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 L0,100 L100,100 L100,0 L0,0 Z 

M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0
M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0
M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0
M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 M0,0 L0,100 L100,100 L100,0 L0,0 Z
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Stop calling Path.Flatten after you've already flattened it?

Comment: @Ken-White    This is sample PathData: 'M0,0 L0,100 L100,100 L100,0 L0,0 Z'       Please test Circle sample : 'M50,50 C50,23 28,0 0,0 C-27,0 -50,22 -50,50 C-50,77 -28,100 0,100 C27,100 50,78 50,50'